# .htaccess match anything and send to PHP file

Tags: php, .htaccess

My regex tries to match all results and redirect to a page.  I want to send the address requested to the page:

```
RewriteRule ^/[\w\W]*$ processor.php [R,NC,L]
```

For instance, my address is:

```
www.mywebsite.com/mySecretCode123
```

I want my php file to be able to read it:

```php
<?php echo $mySecretCode123; /* outputs 'mySecretCode123' */ ?>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.htaccees

```
# RewriteCond is condition - make rewrite only if file doesn't exists
# (.+) means "any character, one or more"
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ processor.php?mySecretCode=$1
```

PHP

```
<?php echo $_GET['mySecretCode']; ?>
```

Comment: I am using `RewriteRule ^/[\w\W]*$ processor.php?key=$1 [R,NC,L]` instead of the `(.*)` because I think it may be faster.  Is this true, do you think?

Comment: @user1477388 i am not sure, but i think it's same or faster. But you should take care more about php,db speed than mod_rewrite speed.

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is not for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ processor.php?$1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer.